# My app crashes when trying to do something with a caught exception

Tags: android, exception, jsonexception

Ok

```
try {
```

```
            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
```

//ERROR WHEN INERTING CODE HERE!.

`}<code>`

Hi guys!, I just want to know why my app crashes when I write code in the indicated place (see above).. If I leave it blank, nothing happens...

The thing is, I want to show a

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Couldn't reach the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Why do you think that is?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do a project clean (Project ->Clean) and try again. If it again crashes, pls post the logcat messages.

Comment: Please post all relevant code and logcat. From this, there is no way for us to know what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming because you're error is

> "Couldn't reach the server"

you are trying to make network calls, which means your code is in a thread of some sort? You cannot touch UI elements from inside the main thread so move:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Couldn't reach the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Into the `postExecute()` method of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

> Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread.

Comment: Yesss :) it worked, thanks guys. I'm new to android. I can't access to UI elements if I'm not in the main thread! got it!

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to access UI elements from outside the main thread by any chance? Try using Log.v instead of Toast and see if that helps.

Comment: Yesss :) it worked, thanks guys. I'm new to android. I can't access to UI elements if I'm not in the main thread! got it!